# neural network not able to predict multiclass output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am making a neural network model for a multiclass classification problem. I want to only use 1 layer since I will need to extract the weight for another problem set and the weight should only be the same number as the independent variable. I kept facing a problem where my model seem to be bad and shows that in my confusion matrix, the model won't predict all classes. Here is what my data looks like (independent variable being t1-t6 and dependent variable being score).

| reviewId | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 | t6 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | -3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 02 | 0 | 0 | 38 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 03 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| etc. |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The range of "t1 - t6" is [-infinity to -infinity]. The range of "score" is [1-5], in which I want to do a multiclass classification. Here is how my code looks like...

```
num_classes = 5
model_relu = Sequential()
model_relu.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(X.shape[1],), activation='relu')) # input shape is (features,). 1 hidden layer with 6 neurons
model_relu.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model_relu.summary()
# compile the model
model_relu.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', # this is different instead of binary_crossentropy (for regular classification)
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# early stopping callback
# This callback will stop the training when there is no improvement in  
# the validation loss for 10 consecutive epochs.  
es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', 
                                   mode='min',
                                   patience=10, 
                                   restore_best_weights=True) # important - otherwise you just return the last weigths...

# now we just update our model fit call
history = model_relu.fit(X,
                    dummy_y,
                    callbacks=[es],
                    epochs=8000000, # you can set this to a big number!
                    batch_size=10000,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    verbose=1)
preds = model_relu.predict(X) # see how the model did!
print(preds[0]) # i'm spreading that prediction across nodes and they sum to 1
print(np.sum(preds[0])) # sum it up! Should be 1
# confusion matrix
matrix = confusion_matrix(dummy_y.argmax(axis=1), preds.argmax(axis=1))
matrix
```

Now my result for confusion matrix shows...

```
array([[ 32141,      0,      0,      0, 114766],
       [  3500,      0,      0,      0,  19625],
       [  2541,      0,      0,      0,  27617],
       [  1657,      0,      0,      0,  42156],
       [ 10333,      0,      0,      0, 724463]])
```

and model evaluation showing...

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.64      0.22      0.33    146907
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00     23125
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00     30158
           3       0.00      0.00      0.00     43813
           4       0.78      0.99      0.87    734796

    accuracy                           0.77    978799
   macro avg       0.28      0.24      0.24    978799
weighted avg       0.68      0.77      0.70    978799
```

Am I making any mistakes with my codes? As it only predicts scores of only 1 and 5 (no prediction on 2, 3, 4). Or do you have any recommendations on other algorithms which might be better?

Answer (score 0):

Let's visualize your model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(6,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=False, to_file='model.png')
```

Result:

[image]

Your network has two layers: an output layer with 10 units, and before that a hidden layer with 1 hidden unit. Obviously the hidden layer is a severe bottleneck and will cause problems -- and according to your description it should not even be there.

Whether your approach of training a network and using the weights for something else is a good one is another question, though (note that if you only train one output layer -- that is, a logistic regression model -- you will get a weight matrix with shape (input_size, num_classes) and not a vector with shape (input_size,) the way you say you need it). Also, such a simple model may simply not be enough to get a good accuracy.